# Sort array of objects by array of indexes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort an array of objects by array of keys. I searched through similar questions but I didn't find anything that could help me

Example:

```js
const data = [
 { label: 'String'},
 { label: 'Number'},
 { label: 'Boolean'},
 { label: 'Array'}
]

const order = [2, 3]
```

Expected result:

```js
const data = [
 { label: 'Boolean'},
 { label: 'Array'},
 { label: 'String'},
 { label: 'Number'}
]
```

The problems that I'm facing are

- `order` array can have or can not have the same length like `data`, the items key that not exists in `order` must go to the bottom
- `data` objects has not an order key to help sort the element, the ordering will made by array object key position

What I tried but not working

```js
data.sort((a, b) => {
 const aIndex = data.indexOf(a);
 const bIndex = data.indexOf(b);

 if(aIndex !== -1) return -1;
 if(bIndex !== -1) return 1;
 
 return order.indexOf(aIndex) - order.indexOf(bIndex);
})
```

Comment: How does `[2,3]` affect the output? The output you've shown seems to just be alphanumerically sorted.

Comment: In the `order` array I store the objects initial position that I want to sort and the new position that I want to put that object . The label string is only an exemple, it can be every text

Comment: Does it have to be sorted in place, or is returning a sorted copy acceptable?

Answer (score 4):

You can just use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to map the data as you need, like this:

```js
const data = [
 { label: 'String'},
 { label: 'Number'},
 { label: 'Boolean'},
 { label: 'Array'}
]

const order = [2, 3];

const out = [...new Set([...order.map(i => data[i]), ...data])];

console.log(out);
```

Comment: My mistake was that I focused only on the sort method. Your solution seems very "clean". Thanks!

Comment: Sorting in such cases is unnecessary and not optimal, here you just need to transform some known data.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a sort, implement a straight-forward algorithm in two steps:

1. Run through the `order` list and extract the corresponding items of `data` into a new list (the sorted list). Replace the extracted values with `undefined` in `data`.
2. Run through `data` and append each item that is not `undefined` to the sorted list.

```js
const data = [
 { label: 'Test 3'},
 { label: 'Test 4'},
 { label: 'Test 1'},
 { label: 'Test 2'}
];

const order = [2, 3, 1, 5];


// Create a working copy of `data` (to not modify `data`)
const work = [...data];

// The sorted list
const sorted = [];

// Step 1
// Run through `order` and move the items from `work` to `sorted` in the provided order
order.forEach((index) => {
  const item = data[index];
  // There is nothing to do if `index` is an invalid index (or `data` does not contain anything at that position)
  if (item !== undefined) {
    sorted.push(item);
    work[index] = undefined;
  }
});

// Step 2
// Move the remaining items (they are not mentioned in `order`)
work.forEach((item) => {
  // Ignore the items that were moved on the first step
  if (item !== undefined) {
    sorted.push(item);
  }
});

// Cleanup
delete work;

// Check the output visually
console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract elements from `order` and then add those not in `order`:

```js
const data = [
    { label: 'String'},
    { label: 'Number'},
    { label: 'Boolean'},
    { label: 'Array'}
]

const order = [2, 3]

result = [
    ...order.map(i => data[i]),
    ...data.filter((_, i) => !order.includes(i)),
]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I really like @n--'s approach. However, it will run into difficulties if a certain value appears multiple times in the array. These problems can be overcome very easily when we build the `Set` with indexes instead of values of `data`:

```js
const data = [
 { label: 'String'},
 { label: 'Number'},
 { label: 'Boolean'},
 { label: 'Array'},
 { label: 'String'}
];
const order = [2, 3];
const out = [...new Set([...order,...data.keys()])].map(i=>data[i]);

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Agree, this is an edge case which may exist in a buggy application. But usually, multiple references of the same object are undesired in a list, that could cause much more *difficulties*, so the `Set` behavior in such cases could easily be a useful feature.

Comment: Right, @n--! I overlooked the fact that my example would _still work_ with your original `Set` approach. I used different objects. Still, in a wider sense, and especially when the array contains primitives instead of objects, the above mentioned problems might occur.